# Why Use JavaScript to change elements and the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to programming and i've learned some HTML fundamentals with CSS. Now I'm learning some Javascript in order to use the combo of these three to make a decent website.

While following a Javascript course, I've got to the changing elements and DOM things chapter and something actually intrigued me, maybe because I'm new. Why would you use some Javascript for changing the class id attributes of an element when you can just do it in your HTML code? I mean if you want to change the class of an element you just have to go to the HTML code, find it, and rename it?

This may seem a stupid question I know. Your opinions and clarification about how Javascript is used for this in general are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why use it to change classes? Example: Switch visibility of an element by adding/removing a class like "is-hidden", while in your css you have ".is-hidden { display: none; }"

Comment: because not everything in a webpage is static. If it were just plain old text based page with no interactions, than there would be no need for JavaScript.

Comment: Hey Zaki, your question might be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You might want to check [ask]. Apart from that, we use JavaScript for any *dynamic* functionality that is supposed to happen client-side. You might want to change the class of an element in order to change its appearance once the user performs a certain action.

Comment: thanks for your answer guys ! but if you can give More clarification epascarello please :p

Comment: What do you need clarifying? @epascarello comment is exactly the answer. If you're changing something in the HTML you don't need JS.

Comment: How are you going to manage something like a popup warning message without Javascript?

Comment: I miss the term DHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well javascript can change `classes`, `ids` and lots of other things depending on what the user does.

So with javascript you can do something if the user clicks, scrolls or just moves the mouse. Or even if something happens from your javascript code you can trigger an event doing something else ...

**Here a little story that might helps:**

Imagine you have a website on `http://my-site.com` Now if a user visits your website he makes one request and gets the page with the HTML, CSS and javascript and images

Now you might want to add something to the image if he clicks on it. So you need to add a class or something when he clicks. Because the click is not making a new request to the server. This just happens inside the browser with the code he loaded on that first request. Or, you might want that the click does make a new request to the server and grabs some information. And then you just want to update a little part. Like one HTML element inside your page with this new information. Without reloading the entire website. Thats also possible with javascript. But not without.

Comment: thanks a lot :) , i do understand it more now

Comment: @ZaKiSB You're welcome, glad it helped! Please consider accepting the answer and the correct answer. And see those things here on stackoverflow changing when you click on the message notification counter, color changes, upvoting or accepting the answer then some thing gets colored green... that's all javascript.

Comment: @ZaKiSB: another example: without JavaScript you wouldn't be able to comment here without page reload. Commenting would feel slower (because page reload) and less convenient. JavaScript (and all the related browser APIs) let you react to user interaction faster, providing a more pleasant user experience.

Comment: @caramba hahaha thanks my man , i did upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript you can *dynamically* change these properties. E.g. you can use JavaScript to change the class when a user clicks a button.

Answer (score 0):

- HTML: The skeleton of your website
- CSS: The appearance of your website
- Javascript: The ability to modify things dynamically/automatically

`Example`: [JSFiddle HTML/CSS/JavaScript example](https://jsfiddle.net/g1ck0ta0/)

In this example we use your idea of changing a class from one element to another, but without going directly to the HTML and changing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a full stack website and you have to interact with clients, for example sign up forms, if there was a validation problem you will need to till the user about it, how? by changing some of the attributes in the html page, but this will be handled using javascript functions.
That what makes javascript interesting.